# abcpdf doesnt add bookmark when you append a pdf from a url

Tags: vb.net, abcpdf

```
Dim mainDoc As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc()
Dim pdfDoc As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc()
mainDoc.Append(pdfDoc) 'merge page one
mainDoc.Page = mainDoc.AddPage()
mainDoc.AddHtml("<P><B>Description:</B>  Sample Desc </P><BR><BR>")
mainDoc.AddBookmark("1 Intro", True)
mainDoc.Page = mainDoc.AddPage()
mainDoc.AddHtml("<P><B>second page:</B>  Sample Desc </P><BR><BR>")
mainDoc.AddBookmark("1 second page", True)

'Everything fine till this
Dim testDoc As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc()
testDoc.Read("www.google.com")
mainDoc.Append(testDoc)
mainDoc.AddBookmark("3 Google page", True)
```

'The last google page bookmark is not working, always pointing to the First page (Intro)

Can anyone help me with this...?. I want to append a doc and add bookmark to it.

Thanks
Anbu

Comment: Got it working.  Need to specify the pagenumber for the maindoc before adding bookmark.

    Dim pageNum =  mainDoc.PageCount
    Dim testDoc As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc()
    testDoc.Read("www.google.com")
    mainDoc.Append(testDoc)
    mainDoc.PageNumber = pageNum +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working.  Need to specify the pagenumber for the maindoc before adding bookmark.

```
Dim pageNum =  mainDoc.PageCount
Dim testDoc As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc()
testDoc.Read("www.google.com")
mainDoc.Append(testDoc)
mainDoc.PageNumber = pageNum +1
mainDoc.AddBookmark("3 Google page", True)
```